# Cant open a doc file from the browser

Tags: java, jsp, ms-word

I have a link using  tag and it is linked to a .doc file in the server. When I click on the link, instead of giving the open, save box, it opens the file in the browser in the binary format. Has anyone encountered this problem? I am using a Weblogic server.

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

As Russ said, sometimes you have to add the `Content-Type` header to explicitly set the mime type; and sometimes, you also have to add a `Content-Disposition` header, perhaps to a value like

> "attachment; filename=doc1.doc"

If Russ' fix doesn't work for you, try adding this additional header.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the MIME Type, possibly to application/msword or application/doc

EDIT:
If the server doesn't know the mime type of the file then it defaults to text/plain and displays the bytes.